# Kendo UI Framework : Upload component not showing options to upload on iPad

Tags: ios, ipad, kendo-ui-angular2

Example  I prepared works fine on a Desktop specifically with  upload and remove  file browse dialog comes in but  when I tried on safari in Ipad  upload option  then remove option  then trying  select option it  look likes a input and keyboard pops up instead of asking for the upload option again.

I am providing link below of the example .Please  can anyone explain issue why its not working on Ipad.
Thanks

Basic usage example as on Telerik site: [Upload Component](http://www.telerik.com/kendo-angular-ui/components/upload/)

Answer (score 0):

We are aware of the mentioned problem. A fix will be pushed later today.